# Jquery .slideup function won't hide div

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to show and hide a div called "map"
When a link with id 'goo' is clicked the map is shown using .slideDown, but when the link is clicked again it is SUPPOSE to use .slideUp to hide the map but nothing happens.

Here is the Javascript:

```
 $('#goo').live('click',function()  {
   if ($("#map").css('visibility','hidden')){
     $('#map').slideDown('slow');
     $("#map").css('visibility','visible');
     $("#map").css('position','relative');
  } else {
    $('#map').slideUp('slow');
  }
  return false;
  });
```

If anyone has any idea where the div won't slide up, let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to answer your question why it doesn't work...your if condition needs to be changed... else everything else is good.... you need to check

```
 if($("#map").css('visibility') == 'visible')
```

else its good

check out the fiddle for the same http://jsfiddle.net/xsFRJ/

Answer (score 2):

Use **[slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)** method

```
$('#goo').live('click',function()  {
    $('#map').slideToggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` functions do not affect the CSS `visibility` property. You should use `display: none;` rather than `visibility: hidden` to better conform to the functions you are trying to use.

Here is a jsfiddle of using `display: none;`: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/2QWEM/1/

If you want your element to still take-up space while it's invisible, then I suggest using `opacity: 0;` and animating the opacity of the element:

```
 $('#goo').live('click',function()  {
   if ($("#map").css('opacity') == 0){
     $('#map').animate({opacity : 1}, 500);
  } else {
    $('#map').animate({opacity : 0}, 500);
  }
  return false;
  });
```

Docs for `.slideUp()`: http://api.jquery.com/slideup

On a side-note, you are using the same selector many times-over, you can chain function calls and cache your selectors to improve performance. Here is an example using your code:

```
$('#goo').live('click',function()  {
    var $map = $('#map');
    if ($map.css('visibility','hidden')){
        $map.slideDown('slow').css({
            visibility : 'visible',
            position   : 'relative'
        }
     } else {
        $map.slideUp('slow');
     }
     return false;
});
```